# IllegalArgumentException when calling Tile#updateTile() in TileService#onStartListening()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

Some users of my app are experiencing a crash I cannot reproduce. It is just a small percentage of the users which are receiving this crash, but currently it is the largest crash in my app, which I would like to solve.  This is the stack trace I received in Firebase Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileLifecycleManager@775810d
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1947)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
    at android.service.quicksettings.IQSService$Stub$Proxy.updateQsTile(IQSService.java:215)
    at android.service.quicksettings.Tile.updateTile(Tile.java:182)
    at com.my.app.MyTileService.updateTile(SourceFile:110)
    at com.my.app.MyTileService.onStartListening(SourceFile:83)
    at android.service.quicksettings.TileService$H.handleMessage(TileService.java:407)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

The crash only occurs on Android 8-9. The crash appears on all sort of devices, including the Google Pixel. Strangely enough it doesn't happen on Samsung devices.

The `MyTileService` class overrides the method `onStartListening()` and then calls `updateTile()`. This is the code (Kotlin):

```
package com.my.app

import android.service.quicksettings.TileService
...

class MyTileService : TileService() {

    override fun onStartListening() {
        super.onStartListening()
        updateTile() // line 83
    }

    private fun updateTile() {
        // qsTile is the same as calling getQsTile()
        qsTile?.apply {

            state = ...
            label = ...
            icon = ...

            // Because of the way how Kotlin works, this calls qsTile.updateTile() and not the updateTile() method above.
            updateTile() // line 110.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mute it. It's not an issue.

Comment: @TheWanderer Could you explain? Why isn't this an issue if it crashes the app? I just checked the Play Console and also have the same crash report there.

Comment: Because it's something you can't avoid or fix. It happens when Android is shutting down, and the user won't notice. See how it's complaining that a Service in System UI isn't registered?